# How to create a clickable image for full screen display in quasar framework

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a image gallery created using the code below. It lays out a grid of 9 q-img tags with the correct image. I am trying to add a button to the bottom right that will allow the image to open as full screen in an overlay. However, it does not seem like quasar has a overlay component unless I am missing it. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this with purely quasar functionality?

```
<template>
  <div class="service-block q-pa-lg text-center column no-wrap flex-center block-wrapper" id="RecentWork">
    <h2 class="text-h2 text-weight-bolder text-dark q-mb-xs">RECENT WORK</h2>
    <h6 class="text-h6 text-weight-light text-dark q-my-none" style="max-width: 800px;">We are a one stop shop for all your home remodeling needs. Check out some of our recent jobs below!</h6>
  </div>
  <q-tabs
        v-model="tab"
        outside-arrows
        mobile-arrows
        inline-label
        active-color="primary"
        indicator-color="primary"
        class="text-grey-7"
      >
        <q-tab name="decks" label="DECKS" class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" active-class="active-menu-item"></q-tab>
        <q-tab name="interior" label="INTERIOR REMODELING" class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" active-class="active-menu-item"></q-tab>
        <q-tab name="exterior" label="EXTERIOR REMODELING" class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" active-class="active-menu-item"></q-tab>
        <q-tab name="new" label="NEW CONSTRUCTION" class="q-pa-md q-ma-md menu-item" active-class="active-menu-item"></q-tab>
    </q-tabs>

    <q-tab-panels v-model="tab" animated>
          <q-tab-panel name="decks">
            <div class="row q-pa-md block-wrapper text-center q-col-gutter-md" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
              <div v-for="item in imagesArray[0]['decks']" :key="item.id" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                  <q-img :src="item.link" :ratio="16/9" class="rounded-borders"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </q-tab-panel>
          <q-tab-panel name="interior">
            <div class="row q-pa-md block-wrapper text-center q-col-gutter-md" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
              <div v-for="item in imagesArray[0]['interior']" :key="item.id" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                  <q-img :src="item.link" :ratio="16/9" class="rounded-borders"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </q-tab-panel>
          <q-tab-panel name="exterior">
            <div class="row q-pa-md block-wrapper text-center q-col-gutter-md" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
              <div v-for="item in imagesArray[0]['exterior']" :key="item.id" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                  <q-img :src="item.link" :ratio="16/9" class="rounded-borders"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </q-tab-panel>
          <q-tab-panel name="new">
            <div class="row q-pa-md block-wrapper text-center q-col-gutter-md" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
              <div v-for="item in imagesArray[0]['newConstruction']" :key="item.id" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                  <q-img :src="item.link" :ratio="16/9" class="rounded-borders"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </q-tab-panel>
    </q-tab-panels>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const imagesArray = [{
    decks:[{ id: 1, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/615.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 2, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/619.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 3, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/627.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 4, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/655.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 5, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/659.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 6, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/666.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 7, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/668.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 8, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/677.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 9, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/decks/678.jpg', import.meta.url).href}],
    interior:[{ id: 1, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/2633.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 2, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/989.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 3, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/1015.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 4, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/2671.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 5, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/1020.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 6, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/2123.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 7, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/2634.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 8, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/1406.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 9, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/interior/2041.jpeg', import.meta.url).href}],
    exterior: [{ id: 1, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/642.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 2, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/651.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 3, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/652.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 4, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/672.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 5, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/711.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 6, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/722.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 7, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/732.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 8, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/748.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 9, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/exterior/762.jpg', import.meta.url).href}],
    newConstruction: [{ id: 1, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/618.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 2, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/626.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 3, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/630.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 4, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/657.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 5, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/710.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 6, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/716.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 7, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/758.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 8, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/799.jpg', import.meta.url).href},
        { id: 9, link: new URL('../assets/imgs/recentwork/construction/850.jpg', import.meta.url).href}]
  }]

  const slide = ref(1)
  const tab = ref('decks')

</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .block-wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .active-menu-item{
    background-color: $background-accent;
    color: $primary !important;
  }

  .menu-item{
    letter-spacing: .15rem;
    font-weight:500;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color:$dark
  }
</style>
```